# High accuracy but dice coefficient 0 in image segmentation with U-Net

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a classical U-Net for brain tumor segmentation.
After the training I obtain high accuracies but dice coefficient 0. I think to have some problems with the masks but I cannot figure out how to solve.
After data pre-processing I have a folder containing MRI images as numpy arrays with dimension (112, 192, 160, 3), where 112 are the number of slices, 192 the height, 160 the width and 3 the number of channels (each one representing one image modality); dtype float64.
For the masks I have the dimension (112,192,160,3), dtype float64.; each channel represents the mask of one tumor region, obtained with the following code:

```
#Split masks in 3 classes (to segment): WT= whole tumor, TC= tumor contour and ET= 
enhancing tumor

def mask_split(mask):

mask_WT = mask.copy()
mask_WT[mask_WT == 1] = 1
mask_WT[mask_WT == 2] = 1
mask_WT[mask_WT == 4] = 1

mask_TC = mask.copy()
mask_TC[mask_TC == 1] = 1
mask_TC[mask_TC == 2] = 0
mask_TC[mask_TC == 4] = 1

mask_ET = mask.copy()
mask_ET[mask_ET == 1] = 0
mask_ET[mask_ET == 2] = 0
mask_ET[mask_ET == 4] = 1

mask = np.stack([mask_WT, mask_TC, mask_ET])

return mask
```

The masks originally have these labels:
-LABEL 0: Unlabeled volume
-LABEL 1: Necrotic and non-enhancing tumor core (NCR\ET)
-LABEL 2: Peritumoral edema (ED)
-LABEL 3: Missing (no pixels in all the volumes contain label 3)
-LABEL 4: GD-enhancing tumor

I have created this data generator:

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

def __init__(self, list_img_IDs, img_path, mask_path, to_fit=True, dim=(102,192,160), batch_size = 1, n_channels = 3, shuffle=True):
    'Initialization'
    self.dim = dim
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.list_img_IDs = list_img_IDs #list of all 'image' ids to use in the generator
    self.to_fit = to_fit #True to return X (img) and Y (masks), False to return X only
    self.img_path = img_path
    self.mask_path = mask_path
    self.n_channels = n_channels #number of image channels
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.on_epoch_end()

def __len__(self):
    'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
    return int(np.floor(len(self.list_img_IDs) / self.batch_size)) 


def __getitem__(self, index):
    'Generate one batch of data'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

    # Find list of IDs
    list_IDs_temp = [self.list_img_IDs[k] for k in indexes]


    # Generate data
    X = self._generate_X(list_IDs_temp)

    if self.to_fit:

      Y=self._generate_Y(list_IDs_temp)

      return X,Y

    else:

      return X
  
def on_epoch_end(self):
    'Updates indexes after each epoch'
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_img_IDs))
    if self.shuffle == True:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

def _generate_X(self, list_IDs_temp):
    'Generates data containing batch_size images' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    X = np.zeros((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
    #Generate data
    for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
      #Store samples
      X[i,]=np.load(self.img_path + '/' + ID)
    
    return X/np.max(X)

def _generate_Y(self, list_IDs_temp):
    'Generates data containing batch_size images' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    Y = np.zeros((self.batch_size, *self.dim, 3))
    #Generate data
    for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
      #Store samples
      Y[i,]=np.load(self.mask_path + '/' + ID) 
    
    return Y
```

The model is constructed in this way:

```
kernel_initializer =  'he_uniform' 

def simple_unet_model(IMG_DEPTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS, num_classes):
#Build the model
inputs = Input((IMG_DEPTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
s = inputs

#Contraction path
c1 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(s)
c1 = Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c1)
p1 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c1)

c2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p1)
c2 = Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c2)
p2 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c2)
 
c3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p2)
c3 = Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c3)
p3 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c3)
 
c4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p3)
c4 = Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c4)
p4 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(c4)
 
c5 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p4)
c5 = Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c5)

#Expansive path 
u6 = Conv3DTranspose(128, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u6)
c6 = Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c6)
 
u7 = Conv3DTranspose(64, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u7)
c7 = Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c7)
 
u8 = Conv3DTranspose(32, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u8)
c8 = Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c8)
 
u9 = Conv3DTranspose(16, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
u9 = concatenate([u9, c1])
c9 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u9)
c9 = Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c9)
 
outputs = Conv3D(num_classes, (1, 1, 1), activation='softmax')(c9)
 
model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
#compile model outside of this function to make it flexible. 
model.summary()

return model

model = simple_unet_model(112, 192, 160, 3, 3)
```

Then I defined dice loss function and dice coefficients:

```
# dice loss as defined above for 3 classes
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1.0):
    class_num = 3
    for i in range(class_num):
        y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true[:,:,:,:,i])
        y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred[:,:,:,:,i])
        intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
        loss = ((2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth))
 
        if i == 0:
            total_loss = loss
        else:
            total_loss = total_loss + loss
    total_loss = total_loss / class_num
    return total_loss

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1-dice_coef(y_true, y_pred,smooth=1.0)
 
# define per class evaluation of dice coef

def dice_coef_necrotic(y_true, y_pred, epsilon=1e-2):
    intersection = K.sum(K.abs(y_true[:,:,:,:,0] * y_pred[:,:,:,:,0]))
    return (2. * intersection) / (K.sum(K.square(y_true[:,:,:,:,0])) + K.sum(K.square(y_pred[:,:,:,:,0])) + epsilon)

def dice_coef_edema(y_true, y_pred, epsilon=1e-2):
    intersection = K.sum(K.abs(y_true[:,:,:,:,1] * y_pred[:,:,:,:,1]))
    return (2. * intersection) / (K.sum(K.square(y_true[:,:,:,:,1])) + K.sum(K.square(y_pred[:,:,:,:,1])) + epsilon)


def dice_coef_enhancing(y_true, y_pred, epsilon=1e-2):
    intersection = K.sum(K.abs(y_true[:,:,:,:,2] * y_pred[:,:,:,:,2]))
    return (2. * intersection) / (K.sum(K.square(y_true[:,:,:,:,2])) + K.sum(K.square(y_pred[:,:,:,:,2])) + epsilon)
```

The model is compiled and trained:

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=dice_coef_loss, 
metrics=['accuracy',dice_coef,dice_coef_edema,dice_coef_enhancing,dice_coef_necrotic])

earlystop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=5, verbose=1, restore_best_weights=True)
callbacks = [earlystop]

history =  model.fit(training_generator,
                     epochs=40,
                     steps_per_epoch=len(train_ids),
                     callbacks= callbacks,
                     validation_data = valid_generator,
                     verbose=1)
```

The problem is that I get high accuracy but from the second epoch on all dice coefficients are 0.